# XML Serialization: object not serialized

Tags: xml-serialization

I'm getting an "`Unspecified error`" when I try to call a particular web-service method.  Using XMLSpy I discover that the parameter object just hasn't been serialized.

In the generated serializer source I note the lines:

```
if (!needType) {
  System.Type t = o.GetType();
  if (t == typeof(global::moonraker1.Conference)) {
  }
  else {
    throw CreateUnknownTypeException(o);
  }
}
```

However, the wsdl import had created a unit called `moonraker1.BookingService`, so the type of the parameter object is actually `moonraker1.BookingService.Conference`.  It seems entirely possible that this is why the object isn't serialised, although I don't understand why the message still appears to be passed to the web service.

Please can anyone shed any light on this?  Or am I on entirely the wrong track?

Comment: which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: That code is not Delphi, is this question tagged correctly?

Comment: Is the parameter object marked as optional in the wsdl? If so, you have to set the `ParameterSpecified` field to true in order to serialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm not sure if this is it, but it looks like some .NET code. 
Maybe the answer is as simple as you need to have a **default constructor** in your type.

My own experience from serialization in .NET is that most of the time it's just because I have written a custom constructor and then forgot to write a default constructor afterwards..